# White rectangles on screen

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics, screen, gnome-classic

My screen frequently doesn't refresh correctly and white rectangles remain. What can I do?

My graphics adapter is
*00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)*

(printed by lspci)

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 in the Classic session, with no effects.

**[UPDATE] Natty uses Intel video driver version 2.14. I downloaded the sources for the Oneiric version, which is 2.15, from packages.ubuntu.com. Compiled the kernel module and installed it using *make install*. I copied the file *intel_drv.so*, which was located in a directory inside */usr/local/lib*, to the corresponding */usr/lib* directory and renamed the existing *intel_drv.so* file. Xorg.0.log now shows driver version 2.15, but the problem still occurs. Maybe I made a mistake or missed something?**

Here are two screenshots that illustrate the bug at 1366x768 and 1024x768:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's happening if you mouse over those rectangles? Can you try to disable Unity (if you're running 11.04 or later of course).

Comment: Hi bakytn, I am running 11.04/Natty. I am working with the classic Ubuntu interface now. Same problem here. If I move the mouse over the rectangles, they sometimes disappear (inside menus in Eclipse for instance), others don't. The _xrefresh_ command makes them disappear sometimes too, but not always. They happen quite often and are quite annoying.

Comment: do they disappear if you use "classic with no effects"? if it works  its a compiz issue.  It would be useful to know what your graphics card is (add it to your question) - and if you have any graphics drivers installed.

Comment: I am using "classic with no effects". I'm sure it isn't a compiz issue. I added my graphics card to my question (lspci output). I don't think I have a graphics driver installed, at least I didn't install it myself.

Comment: What is your screen resolution?

Comment: resolution: 1366x768

Comment: @user22611 Is it possible for you to post a picture or screencast showing your problem in more detail?

Comment: I have exactly the same graphic controller as yours, exactly. I am not experiencing issues like that. Do you have any big and non standard packages installed? Is it a fresh install?

Comment: I didn't install any packages.

Comment: I have 2 pics. How can I post them?

Comment: Did you install 64bit versoin of 32 bit? (I am running 64 bit version). Your hardware can't be old with this graphics controllers or is it?

Comment: It is 64bit. My hardware is bought 2011, it is a new machine.

Comment: hmm. Try to change screen resolution to lower or even higher.

Comment: This is a 1366x768 Laptop display. Resolution change is not an option.

Comment: Are you sure you can't change it to lower resolution?

Comment: I tried 1024x768 (see screenshot link in question), huge gray rectangles instead of white rectangles, but still rectangles :-(

Comment: I have the same issue. Core i3 2nd generation integrated graphics.

Comment: At least something new. Is it happening all the times? I mean..may be it's overheating? this may happen...the other option is to try to completely reinstall it. (also don't forget to keep your system updated, may be they fixed it already)

Comment: How can I see whether it is overheating? The battery runtime is 3-4 hours instead of expected 7 hours, but does this mean the system is overheating? Reinstallation sounds like pure trial and error rather than a plan. And why should I reinstall if I never had a "working" system, regarding the rectangles bug? I don't have that much time :-(

Comment: Important question: Is it a hardware or software problem. If it is a hardware problem: is it a firmware or electronics problem. I need to know this because I need to know if I should return the machine to the dealer.

Comment: Try putting the latest oneiric daily build onto a USB stick and boot from that.  Do you have the same issue?

Comment: I tried the Alpha 3 of Oneiric. During a short session, the problem did not occur. But I still need to test it with a higher (graphics) mem load. But why doesn't the 2.15 driver work in Natty? Is there a different file involved than _intel_drv.so_?

Comment: How can I make it work in Natty? Why is the 2.15 driver of Oneiric different? What else can I exchange apart from _intel_drv.so_? Experts, please answer. Another 2 months, until Oneiric is available, with this annoying bug are almost unbearable!!

Comment: Nobody well versed in display drivers?

Comment: Hey this is started to me as well :D Exactly the same problem. Were you able to fix that?

Comment: Hey this is started to me as well :D Exactly the same problem. Were you able to fix that?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Ubuntu 11.04, classic desktop.  I currently have two blank rectangles on my screen, both approximately 230 x 260 pixels.  If I switch users, they go away; when I switch back to my original session, they reappear.  The do *not* appear in a screen image captured by `xwd`.

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/378932/right-click-menu-mask-persisting-on-my-screen  It's plausible that the white rectangles are the same size and position as a right-click menu from the browser (could be Firefox or Chrome).